# Regex to Match Number of Subdirectories in a URL

Tags: regex

I found an article that almost covered my exact need. However, it needs to be adjusted a bit and I can't quite figure it out.

VARIATION 1: EXACTLY X NUMBERS OF SUB-DIRECTORIES, WITH TRAILING SLASH
This variation assumes each subdirectory ends in a trailing slash.

**Regex for exactly one sub-directory**
^/[^/]+/$

example matching URL path: /retail/

**Regex for exactly two sub-directories**
^/[^/]+/[^/]+/$

example matching URL path: /retail/clothing/

I would like to adjust these two rules to match a specific directory.

In my case, I have a site that has multiple top-level directories (products and stores, each with 2 additionally subdirectories).

I would like to create a regex rule to only target /products/ plus the following 3 subdirectories.

Comment: What regex engine are you using? Are you using a specific language?

Comment: I'm trying to get this to work in Google Analytics.

Comment: https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034324?hl=en It appears Google Analytics doesn't support `\{3}`. You could submit a feature request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don’t have a system to test this, but I think you can use the ‘?’ and parens to add the variable sub-dirs on your base match for “/products/“.

The base regex would be “^/products/$”.
Then to match 0 or 1 subdirectories, you could add “([^/]+/)?”
Add three of these and I think you have the regex to match your base plus 0 to 3 subdirectories. I think that is what you were asking for.

```
^/products/([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?([^/]+/)?$
```

The equivalent RE worked in Emacs for these test lines:

```
/products/
/products/a/
/products/a/b/
/products/a/b/c/
```

And did not match this:

```
/products/a/b/c/d/
```

If you always wanted the 3 subdirectories, drop the ‘?’s to make the extras required.

```
^/products/[^/]+/[^/]+/[^/]+/$
```

Hope this helps!